# Easy method for checking for duplicates and errata in panel dataset

Tags: r, duplicates, conditional-statements, data-mining

Imagine a dataframe:

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble( ~City,  ~Year,  ~Burger_cost,   ~Cola_cost, ~Resident_AVGGrowth_cm,
    "Abu Dhabi",    2020,   2,  3,  175,
    "Abu Dhabi",    2019,   1,  3,  174,
    "Abu Dhabi",    2018,   1,  2,  173,
    "New York", 2020,   4,  5,  500,
    "New York", 2019,   3,  5,  184,
    "New York", 2018,   2,  3,  183,
    "Abu Dhabi",    2020,   2,  3,  175,
    "Abu Dhabi",    2019,   1,  3,  174,
    "Abu Dhabi",    2018,   1,  2,  173,
    "Abu Dhabi",    2017,   1,  NA, 100,
    "London",   2020,   5,  6,  186,
    "London",   2019,   4,  6,  188,
    "London",   2018,   3,  5,  185,
    "New York", 2020,   4,  5,  185,
    "New York", 2019,   3,  5,  184,
    "New York", 2018,   3,  3,  183,
    "London",   2020,   5,  6,  186,
    "London",   2019,   4,  6,  188,
    "London",   2018,   3,  5,  185)
```

The same dataset for visual representation:
[image]

There can be many inputs. For example, data for London is totally similar for all years, so we can delete it. The data for Abu Dhabi is similar for years 2018-2020 and has difference for 2017.
The data for New York contains discrepancy in year 2018 for the Burger cost (and growth of a city resident).
The data for the growth of a city resident is surely erroneus in row 4 for NY (too huge descrepancy), but it has a duplicate value in the row 16 (in this case we would prefer delete row 4 and keep row 16 based on criteria that no person can be shorter than 50 cm and longer than 4 meters [400 cm] [especially in the mean values :)]).
Rows 6 and 16 (for NY, 2018) contain different data for the burger cost which can only be resolved by human (say, variant with 3 USD is correct but R needs to show the fact of discrepancy for the end user).

The question: can you suppose nice and neat methods for performing these operations? What do you usually use to solve such issues.

I just started to think on this issue.
It is an easy task in C#. I am keeping in mind several strategies, but I would be extremely interested to know what ways do you use for solving such issues :) Any ideas are much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps - Grouped by 'City', create a flag for the outliers with `boxplot` on the 'Resident_AVGGrowth_cm', then add 'Year' into the grouping, create another flag for unique values based on the columns `Burger_cost` to `Resident_AVGGrowth_cm` using `n_distinct` and looping over `if_all` (returns TRUE only if all the columns looped for the row are returning TRUE), then grouped by `City`, `filter` out those City having all duplicates e.g. London, as well as remove the rows with outlier_flag

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(City) %>%
   mutate(outlier_flag = Resident_AVGGrowth_cm %in% 
     boxplot(Resident_AVGGrowth_cm, plot = FALSE)$out) %>% 
  group_by(Year, .add = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(flag_all_unq = if_all(Burger_cost:Resident_AVGGrowth_cm,
      ~ n_distinct(.x, na.rm = TRUE) == 1)) %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  filter(!all(flag_all_unq)) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
  filter((!outlier_flag)|flag_all_unq)
```

Comment: Thanks, great. I have an issue with replicability when performing the code: [...your code...] filter((!outlier_flag)|flag_all_unq)
Error in `across()`:
! Must be used inside dplyr verbs.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @AlexanderShemetev In my code, there is no `across` though.  Is it the error from `if_all`.  Can you show your `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: Sure, no problem: packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘1.0.10’

Comment: @AlexanderShemetev your version is recent.  it is not clear why you get `across` error as I didn't use that.  can you try on a fresh R session

Comment: Thanks, it works on a new session. Maybe there is another package function with the same name (if_all).... By the way, the idea to look for outliers with inbuilt boxplot function without plotting the chart is brilliant :)

Comment: @AlexanderShemetev Some function `filter/mutate` etc are in multiple packages (`plyr` e.g), could mask

Comment: This doesn't work when adding other libraries: library(dplyr)
`df1 %>%
   group_by(City) %>%
   mutate(outlier_flag = Resident_AVGGrowth_cm %in% 
     boxplot(Resident_AVGGrowth_cm, plot = FALSE)$out) %>% 
  group_by(Year, .add = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(flag_all_unq = dplyr::if_all(Burger_cost:Resident_AVGGrowth_cm,
      ~ n_distinct(.x, na.rm = TRUE) == 1)) %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  filter(!all(flag_all_unq)) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
  filter((!outlier_flag)|flag_all_unq) #Could you, please, help with masking this function when other libraries are in :)`

Comment: @AlexanderShemetev I am not sure `if_all` is in other packages, anyway, it is always better to use the namespace:: to avoid any masking or when you load a package `library(plyr, exclude = c("filter",...))`. or you can use `library(conflicted);conflict_prefer("if_all", "dplyr")` and other functions

Comment: I found the solution myself - this works well : `library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(City) %>%
   mutate(outlier_flag = Resident_AVGGrowth_cm %in% 
     boxplot(Resident_AVGGrowth_cm, plot = FALSE)$out) %>% 
  group_by(Year, .add = TRUE) %>%
   dplyr::mutate(flag_all_unq = dplyr::if_all(Burger_cost:Resident_AVGGrowth_cm,
      ~ n_distinct(.x, na.rm = TRUE) == 1)) %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  filter(!all(flag_all_unq)) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
  filter((!outlier_flag)|flag_all_unq)` #The error was caused by the "mutate" when using several libraries

Comment: Thanks, your solution is very good. It is neat and short. Thank you very much for it :)